# PowerBI: Difference between values based on columns

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I've got a file that contains quite a bit of data but I have to make it make sense somehow. I'm having trouble distilling the data. The data looks like this

| TransactionState | Date | Number | User |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Open | 01-01-2023 | 100 | UserOne |
| Close | 01-01-2023 | 125 | UserOne |
| Open | 01-01-2023 | 125 | UserOne |
| Close | 02-01-2023 | 130 | UserOne |
| Open | 01-01-2023 | 1 | UserTwo |
| Close | 01-01-2023 | 123 | UserTwo |

What I want is the amount of fully executed transactions (Open, followed by the first Close) with the difference in number per transaction, per user. So expected output of this:

| OpenedOnDate | ClosedOnDate | Used | User |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01-01-2023 | 01-01-2023 | 25 | UserOne |
| 01-01-2023 | 02-01-2023 | 5 | UserOne |
| 01-01-2023 | 01-01-2023 | 122 | UserTwo |

I'm hoping someone can help me with this

Comment: Do they always appear one after the other in sets of two?

Comment: They don't, it could be that UserOne and UserTwo open a transaction one after the other, and UserTwo then closes his transaction before UserOne

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this. You dont have a time, so I assume once the people are grouped, the sequence is in date/time order. It also attempts to account for multiple close rows and picks the first one in a sequence in case the sequence is A/B/C/A/B and not A/B/A/B

```
let  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"User"}, {{"data", each 
     //offset rows
         let MinusOne = #table({"Column1"}, {{null}}) & Table.Skip(Table.DemoteHeaders(Table.RemoveLastN(_,1)),1),
         custom1 = Table.ToColumns(_) & Table.ToColumns(MinusOne ),
         custom2 = Table.FromColumns(custom1,Table.ColumnNames(_)&List.Transform(Table.ColumnNames(_), each _&"_offset")),
     #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(custom2, "Used", each if [TransactionState_offset]="Open" and [TransactionState]="Close" then [Number]-[Number_offset] else null),
     #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Added Custom", each ([Used] <>null))
     in  #"Filtered Rows"
, type table }}),
#"Expanded data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "data", {"Date_offset","Date", "Used"}, {"OpenedOnDate","ClosedOnDate", "Used"}),
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded data",{{"ClosedOnDate", type date}, {"OpenedOnDate", type date}, {"Used", type number}, {"User", type text}})
in #"Changed Type"
```

[image]

Comment: Nice solution as usual.

Comment: Thanks. A nice change from the people who post beginner questions then don't bother to check back for the response or can't decide how to use it

Comment: @horseyride It turns out it didn't work and I saw it wrong. I'll edit the OP with some more details

Comment: try  #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Headers met verhoogd niveau", {"User"}, {{"data", each

Comment: I was doing it in the existing table, where I should be making another one... I wasn't paying attention. Sorry